# events log in cisco

Tags: cisco, cisco-ios, cisco-catalyst

Is there log file just like events file in windows showing what happened,who did what, kind of ? I could not see with show archive log.some switch goes down and support guys plug off/on cisco switch, guessing there is no power on button,and I would like to know what happened to this switch.thanks

Comment: Which Cisco product are you referring to?

Comment: cisco catalyst series

Comment: The internal log is going to be limited, so you can log to an external logging server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see the event log with

```
show logging
```

This assumes you have enabled logging:

(example)

```
logging buffered 32768 informational
```

Note that if someone unplugs the device, it's not going to log that event.

Comment: Is there a reference that shows what is logged in these logs?

Comment: ups,electricity etc problems, are those getting logged?

Comment: No.  There is no power quality monitoring

Comment: at least is there a way to know at a specific time switch went offline and online on device level? I can see it go offline/online nms but can not find any logs to verify it.

Comment: The log would indicate a restart.  But absent an external syslog server, all events prior to the restart would be lost.

Answer (score 0):

`show logging` displays the event log. For some events, you can (and may need to) explicitly configure logging.

Additionally, you can log to an external (syslog) server which can store more entries than the limited internal log and doesn't lose its entries on power loss.

Comment: I thought there is not any log configured.how I can check the status if any log is enabled? sorry for this terrible formatting that I could not put it properly <<# show archive log config all 
% Config Logger disabled.">>

Comment: this is a temp job, I will walk back few days only